# what is the correct way to use cache control "must-revalidate" on dynamically loaded content?

Tags: html, browser-cache

To give a background, I have a very large js file, which is dynamically loaded in a script tag. the file is changed by the client time to time. If there are no changes we dont want a reload.

So, I went thru many stackoverflow articles regarding must-revalidate.
Based on that, I implemented the cache headers to look like this

```
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,max-age=0
```

I also have ETag enabled.
From what I read and understood, this is supposed to check for changes and load only if there are any changed

Problem is that in both Firefox and Chrome, the file is downloaded irrespective of if there are changes or not. ie even when the file and Etag is unchanged, the browser does NOT load from cache.

What is going on in this case?
Am I doing something wrong here?
should I set long maxage when I use must-revalidate, instead of maxage set as zero?

I am editing this question because I found something important while I was checking further. please read below before posting answer.

It seems that this problem described above is only happening on dynamically loaded resources.

eg:
if I have a script tag in the page source

```
<script src="some-js.js" type="text/javascript">
```

this respects the must-revalidate cache headers. and does not reload unless there are changes.

however, if the scritp tag is dynamically loaded (pasting my code for loading the dynamic script tag below)

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute('src', 'newjs.js');
s.setAttribute('id', 'script1');
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.async = false;
s.onerror = errorcallback;
s.onload = loadcallback;
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

this js is always reloaded irrespective of the cache header.

Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Rename JS file so that the name contains file's content hash inside it, for instance: `your_module.489d43f35d9b718c5cdc4f0828a7c6c7.js` and mark the file as [immutable](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/01/using-immutable-caching-to-speed-up-the-web/). This way the client will only download the file once.

Should the contents of the file change, simply generate new file name based on the new content. This technique is often used in [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/) bundler. No need to play with headers anymore!

Answer (score 0):

It is reloading the file every time because you are deactivating any sort of cache with `max-age=0`.

There are two ways in which a browser can confirm whether a file it has in cache is stale:

- ETags
- modification times

Both require that the browser *has* the file in cache, otherwise there's nothing for it to work with either way. For a browser to keep the file in cache, it must be allowed to keep it in cache for some time. That is done by specifying a `max-age` and/or `Expires` header. If that is `0`, then the browser won't cache anything. So, first allow the browser to cache the file at all by setting a positive expiration time.

Next, `must-revalidate` specifies that the browser must check with the server whether a newer file is available. If there is, the server will send the newer file, otherwise the server will respond with an HTTP status code indicating that the browser still has the up-to-date version and will omit sending a lengthy response body. For that to work, there must be a mechanism which browser and server can use to confirm the contents of the file. That's where ETags or modification times come in.

If your server sets an `ETag` header for a file, which typically contains a hash of the file's contents, then the browser can validate it by requesting it with an `If-None-Match` header. If the file's ETag still matches, the server will respond with `304 Not Modified`.
The other alternative is for the server to set a `Last-Modified` header, which allows the browser to request the file with `If-Modified-Since`, and the server again to respond with `304 Not Modified` if the file is still up-to-date.

Without `must-revalidate` the browser would simply use the cached version of the file without contacting the server at all until the file's `max-age`/`Expires` time is reached, and then it may request the file again with `If-None-Match`/`If-Modified-Since`. With the `must-revalidate` directive the browser is instructed to check in with the server every time before using the cached file.

Comment: i dont think it is a problem with max-age. see my new edits in the question (I added after you posted this). if it was problem with max-age, the other resources with the same cached headers would also reload, but this problem is happening only in the dynamically loaded resource.